# Sendmail: how to create a spam folder automatically?

Tags: sendmail, spamassasin

I have a mailserver(sendmail+dovecot+procmail+spamassassin)
Works fine,for normal mail,for spam i want to create a folder called
"Spam" for every user and put all spam mail there.
I configured procmailrc as this

```
:0:
* ^X-Spam-Status: Yes
Spam
```

Restarted sendmail,but no spam folder is created and mail is sent at...dev/null?
How to create automatically a spam folder?

Comment: Apparent cross-site duplicate: http://serverfault.com/questions/735135/procmail-and-thunderbird

Comment: Also, possible duplicate of http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/242035/procmail-first-put-on-spam-then-execute-a-script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found
on procmail

```
DEFAULT=/var/spool/mail/$LOGNAME/new
ORGMAIL=/var/spool/mail/$LOGNAME
MAILDIR=/var/spool/mail/$LOGNAME
DELIVER="/usr/lib/dovecot/deliver -d $LOGNAME"
LOGFILE=/root/procmail.log
VERBOSE=yes

# deliver spam to spam folder

:0
* ^X-Spam-Status: Yes
.Spam/
```

And on dovecot

```
inbox = yes
  #mailbox name {
    # auto=create will automatically create this mailbox.
    # auto=subscribe will both create and subscribe to the mailbox.
    #auto = no

    # Space separated list of IMAP SPECIAL-USE attributes as specified by
    # RFC 6154: \All \Archive \Drafts \Flagged \Junk \Sent \Trash
    #special_use =
  #}

  # These mailboxes are widely used and could perhaps be created automatically:
  mailbox Drafts {
    special_use = \Drafts
    auto = create
  }
  mailbox Spam {
    special_use = \Junk
    auto = subscribe
  }
  mailbox Trash {
    special_use = \Trash
    auto = create
  }
```